# How to add statistic value in SQL

Tags: sql

Now my data table is like

```
uid mid  ..
1   xx   ..
2   xx   ..
-   a    ..
-   b    ..
...
```

I wrote two SQL queries:

`select count(distinct uid) from T where uid!='-'` and `select count(distinc mid) from T where uid='-'`,

Now I wanna to get the sum of those two values in only one SQL query. Anybody has any idea to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(DISTINCT uid) FROM T WHERE uid <> '-') +
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT mid) FROM T WHERE uid = '-') As sumOfTwo
```

or

```
;WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT uid) cnt FROM T WHERE uid <> '-'
), t2 AS (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT mid) cnt FROM T WHERE uid = '-'
)
SELECT t1.cnt + t2.cnt As sumOfTwo
FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2
```

or [Recommanded]

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [uid] <> '-' THEN [uid] END) +
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [uid] = '-' THEN [mid] END)
FROM T
```

Comment: Very helpful and exhaustive! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
select count(distinct uid) from T where uid!='-'
union all
select count(distinc mid) from T where uid='-'
```